# my application is available at play store but for few device it shows " cant install 'app name' "

Tags: android

Recently I've uploaded my app on play store but for most of the devices it shows:

`can't install this app`

My minimum SDK version is 18. Kindly guide me what is the possibility of search error. Thanks

Comment: on which version your app isn't working

Comment: tI don't think it is something you are responsible for. Does this error happens when trying to install the app from google play?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko yes it happens when you are downloading the app from play store, after downloading the app while instaling this error happens, it shows "can't install this app".

Comment: @rachna few of them have 7.0 and 5.1, I don't know exactly about others

Answer (score 0):

It depends on multiple conditions: -
1. did you provided support to tablet? if not then it will not be available for tablets.
2. Are you using any sensor? It will not be installed in device if required sensors not available.
3. Did you declared multiple screen supports?
4. Minimum SDk declared in App.

Comment: I have done all of the above but still, it shows installation error